# C# Windows Form Takes Forever to Load

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, startup

I'm developing a Windows Form launcher / update / splash screen application to be used on a Windows 7 Panasonic Toughbook (Tablet) in C#. The launcher works fine on my desktop and one of my Toughbooks... However, testing on the "real environment" device takes 20+ seconds to even show the form after the first launch. (Once the form is shown, it goes fast, the way the app is suppose to work.) The first launch on the device after installation is quick, but after the first launch, it takes a long time.

I'm not really sure how to go about even testing this, since this is on a device that can't be connected to via USB or put on our network. It doesn't seem to matter if the application opens files or not. In fact in most cases, the app just opens up, see's that it's too soon to check for another update, launches the main app, and kills itself.

The current process looks like this:

constructor:

```
public MyConstructor() { InitializeComponent(); }
```

Form Load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isLoaded)
    {
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap("parentApplication.exe.config"); //Path to your config file
        System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        WebRequest.url = configManager.AppSettings.Settings["SURL"].Value;

        // Set a timer to run the update process momentarily to allow the UI thread to update and display. (UI must be idle to run Timer)
        updateTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        updateTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(beginUpdate);
        updateTimer.Enabled = true;
        isLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Update Process

```
private void beginUpdate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If any of this fails, we still want to launch the main application. 
    try
    {
            // Prevent the timer from doing anything else.
            updateTimer.Enabled = false;

            string version = "0";
            try
            {
                Version v = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("ParentApplication.exe").Version;
                version = v.ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                version = "0";
            }

            updateProgress(5);

            DateTime buffer = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5);
            DateTime last = Convert.ToDateTime(configManager.AppSettings.Settings[lastCheck].Value);
            int comp = DateTime.Compare(buffer, last);

            if (comp < 0)
            {
                // Begin update process
                updateApplication(version);
            }

            updateProgress(100);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            logger.Error("Error in update application.", er);
        }

        // The updater can't update itself. Launch the external application
        // to handle the updating of the updater. This application also launches
        // the main executable.
        Process sync = new Process();
        sync.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        sync.StartInfo.FileName = "FinishUpdate.exe";
        sync.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        sync.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        sync.Start();
        Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: "Hanging" for 20 seconds feels a lot like some sort of timeout.  You mention that the devices are not on the network.  Is there some code (perhaps left over from development?) that attempts to open a network resource?  Does updateApplication() check via the network?

Comment: It opens a connection through a wireless card to a server not on our network. What is interesting is that the form doesn't show up at all for those 20 seconds. Once the form shows up, it does all that stuff fine.

Comment: The form would not show up for the 20 seconds if something (like a network call...) is blocking the message queue.  If you do something that can take a while, do it in a separate thread (BackgroundWorker usually works well in a WinForms context).

Comment: The network call happens inside of "updateApplication" which happens after form load and the UI thread should be idle. But, I will set up some logging as Mackey has stated and see if I can get some more information.

Comment: You are gussing here that UI is idle after Load event and that one second interval is enough. That's a risk. After Load there are Activated, Shown,Paint.... if the WinForms message queue doesn't complete in that one second, you will block it with updateApplication() and your form will not paint itself. I would try with background worker and spin a different thread.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. The config file I am pulling from is the parent applications config file. The current application does not have a config file and it looks like log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); freaks out because of that. I removed that line. Not really sure why I had that line there in the first place. There also appears to be a problem with ATT's wireless card application that goes extremely slow after being hibernated. I also launched everything into the background worker process.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Can you post your comment as an answer? That is the process I used for determining what was going wrong. Don't know why I didn't think of that earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description, a profiler may be difficult to setup. Another option is to run a [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) which logs method execution times to an arbitrary log file. Once you identify which method is performing poorly you can repeat the steps until you narrow down the the line of code causing the bottleneck.